# webmin login redirect issue using apache as proxy

Tags: fedora, apache2, webmin

I have a webmin properly setup using apache as proxy. However, there is a minor issue which is really annoying.

After typing in the username and password, the website failed to redirect to the correct URL.
that means instead of https://webmin.mydomain.com.
it is redirected to https://webmin.mydomain.com:10000 which has the port number appended at the back. Since this port is being blocked on my router, the redirection will simply fail. so how can i make webmin login redirection to go to the correct place without the port being appended at the back?

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
 ServerName xxxx

 ProxyPreserveHost On
 ProxyRequests off
 ProxyPass "/" "https://127.0.0.1:10000/"
 ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://127.0.0.1:10000/"

 SSLProxyEngine on
 SSLProxyVerify none
 SSLProxyCheckPeerCN off
 SSLProxyCheckPeerName off
 SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire off

 SSLEngine on
 SSLCertificateFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx/cert.pem"
 SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx/privkey.pem"
 SSLCertificateChainFile "/etc/letsencrypt/live/xxxx/chain.pem"
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Typically I would terminate the SSL connection in Apache and use a plain http connection to services running on localhost, but that is probably not the issue. In your  `/etc/webmin/config`, did you add the line `referer=webmin.example.com` a suggested in http://www.webmin.com/apache.html?

Comment: anyway i have found the solution. it is an issue in the miniserv.pl